# Apache splitting logs

Tags: apache-2.2, logging

I've a log of a busy website that grows very fast. I'd like to know if there's a way to "split" the log file every day without using external tools.

EDIT: My Fault, I'm on a Windows server 2003, Apache Version 2.0.64.

Comment: My answer below assumes that you have a Linux server not a Windows one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache httpd is capable of writing error and access log files through a pipe to another process, rather than directly to a file. This capability dramatically increases the flexibility of logging, without adding code to the main server. In order to write logs to a pipe, simply replace the filename with the pipe character "|", followed by the name of the executable which should accept log entries on its standard input.

You can use this technique to pipe the logs to a script which then splits the logs in any way you like. This is often used to split by virtual host.

Comment: This is not what I would like to know... I mean: I thought that Apache was able to do it automatically... :(

Comment: @IssamTP - then why did you accept this answer? I agree, this is not the ideal way to accomplish log rotation unless you *really* need the flexibility that this provides. Go with Khaled's solution.

Comment: Pretty hard to say in english: when I say "This is not what I would like to know" I mean that your answer brings bad news for me, not that you gave a bad answer.

Comment: Ahh, understood. Well, I'd still advocate that Khaled's solution is superior. With his solution, you would not have to write a custom log handler.

Comment: No apache does not do this automatically and logrotate is the correct solution in most cases. I added the pipeing answer for completness as it is a useful technique if you need it, in most cases though you would not. I wrote the answer before I saw your meant a windows server I don't know the best answer in that case hopefully someone else does.

Comment: I'll do some C script or something similar on tomorrow.

Answer (score 3):

You can use logrotate to keep your log files small and you can also compress them.

For example, you can use something like:

```
/var/log/apache/*.log {
      daily
      rotate 5
      size 100M
      compress
      postrotate
         /usr/bin/killall -HUP apache
      endscript
 }
```

This will keep five rotated files. The logs will be rotated daily and compressed. For more info, see `man logrotate`.